# Runtime error about sox library in cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, sox

I am trying to sox library into my project and installed library using ./configure, make and make install and  linked to the libsox.dylib into my project.  I am not getting compiler error but getting run time error .

Now i am getting following error,

> ```
> [Session started at 2010-03-03 17:33:44 +0530.]
> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.0.dylib
>   Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libavformat.dylib
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
> /usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
> /usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
>
> The Debugger has exited due to signal 5 (SIGTRAP).The Debugger has exited due to signal 5 (SIGTRAP).
> ```

So anyone please tell me exact procedure to install sox library into mac os.

Regards,
CocoaDev

Answer (score 1):

You're probably trying to mix different architectures, e.g. 32 bit and 64 bit code, or x86 and ARM. Use `file` to check the architecture of the dyld and compare that with the architecture of whatever it is that you are trying to build.

`$ man file`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the quick fix: when you install the program, run "configure" this way:

```
./configure CFLAGS='-O2 -arch x86_64 ...' LDFLAGS='-arch x86_64 ...'
```

List all your desired archs, each with a separate -arch.  This is known to sometimes break.  For example, do NOT compile LibSDL this way, you will get incorrect output (weird colors and stuff).  Unfortunately, it is quite possible that sox suffers from the similar problems, so be sure to test it on all the archs you want to ship with.